Microsoft Fabric: mssparkutils.notebook.exit with multiple values or json/dict
In Fabric, I have a notebook with a dataframe and some aggregations. I'm trying to pass those aggregated values further to outlook365 activity. The simplified version of passing aggregations is as follows:
import json

summa = 250
snitt = 100

result = {
    'sum': summa,
    'snitt': snitt
}

result_json = json.dumps(result)

mssparkutils.notebook.exit(result_json)

Inside outlook365 activity I'm trying to caprure a value of "snitt" like this:
@json(activity('exit').output.result.exitValue.snitt)

But getting an error:
"The expression 'json(activity('exit').output.result.exitValue.snitt)' cannot be evaluated because property 'snitt' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'."
Any workaround for this? My goal is to get some aggregations from notebook and pass them to outlook365.
I tried to parse the value with @json(activity('exit').output.result.exitValue.snitt) or just with @activity('exit').output.result.exitValue.snitt without success.

The exitValue from the notebook activity exit is of string type. That is the reason you are not able to get the value of 'snitt' from that.

img:1 Notebook activity output
The correct way to give the expression is,
@json(activity('exit').output.result.exitValue).snitt

This expression uses the "json" function to parse the "exitValue" string as a JSON object, and then uses the dot notation to extract the "snitt" value from the object.

Thank you for the reply! I'm so sure I tested your solution without success, but now when I tested it it worked. Thank you!

Great to know that it worked now.

@Aswin, I have a follow up question with a slightly more complex problem, if you don't mind. Suppose, that the dict result will containt one key-value pair, where the key is predefined, but values might be a nested dict or list of lists, which will be created dynamically, and I don't know in advance the lenght of it, can be something like this:
result = {
'sum': summa,
'snitt': snitt,
'dynamic_dict': {'key1': 'val1',
'key2': 'val2'
}
we dont know in advance if dynamic_dict will be empty or not.

... this doesn't have to be a nested dict, it can be list of lists, the point is I don't know in advance if it will be empty or not (and how many values it will contain).
How can I dynamically "unpack" it inside the outlook365-activity?
Could you give me a high level overview of how I could achieve it? "If conditions" and "ForEach" activities comes to mind, but I have had time udnerstand the link logic between all these activities at the moment.

I am not sure of your new requirement. You can ask new question on this with detailed explanation of your requirement along with your work. That will give more reach to community and community members might help you
